# Vue Router : Cant define children for default OR main components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, children

First of all I'm learning Vue JS 2 since about a week and I'm stuck on a problem with Vue Router.  I'm pretty sure the solution is right in front of my eyes but I wasn't able to find it yet.

So : On my root route I have 2 views in components Home and NotAuth.
My aim is to display the Login component and others routes related to it when the user isn't logged.
And when the user logs in the Home component is displayed on '/' and all login related routes are not accessible by him.

It works when I'm logged if I try to access '/register' Im instantly redirected to 'Home'.
But when I'm not logged if I try to access say '/add_device' a blank page is displayed.

What I'd like to do is define other routes as Home's children but I cant find anything in the doc explaining how to do so.
I've tried several things and none worked and I'm kind of lost on how to proceed.

If anyone has a clue on how to proceed that would be awesome.
Thanks !!

index.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: '',
    components: {
      login: NotAuth,
      default: Home
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
      },
      {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'Register',
        component: Register
      },
      {
        path: '/reset',
        name: 'ResetPassword',
        component: ResetPassword
      },
      {
        path: '/reset-sent',
        name: 'ResetSent',
        component: ResetSent
      },
      {
        path: '/change-password/:token/:mail',
        name: 'ChangePassword',
        component: ChangePassword
      },
      {
        path: '/confirmation',
        name: 'Confirmation',
        component: Confirmation
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/add_device',
    name: 'device',
    component: Device
  },
  {
    path: '/add_scene',
    name: 'scene',
    component: Scene
  },
  {
    path: '/add_room',
    name: 'room',
    component: Room
  },
]
```

App.vue

```
<div id="app">
  <router-view v-if='userAuthenticated' :username='this.user.first_name' :user='this.user'></router-view>
  <router-view name="login" v-else @isAuth='handle'></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: you never need to use 'this' in templates.  everything is considered 'this'. so `:username='user.first_name'`.